# Create Point - measure distance to point layer- accounting for terrain

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, point

How can I - select a point / location- they pass us a location, that will be a point from one of a series of preexisting layers (which may include lat long or mailing address, but not generally. Generally it will be a preexisting point from a point layer.

We need to measure a straight line from that - selected point - to a bunch of points in 1 other layer.

That's it. - looking for an output of a table of distances and point information.

I have 10.1 advanced (with spatial analyst etc. and enterprise server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for a Tool to Calculate Distance Between Points (Between Layers)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16642/looking-for-a-tool-to-calculate-distance-between-points-between-layers)

Comment: have you looked at this post? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16642/looking-for-a-tool-to-calculate-distance-between-points-between-layers - you might have to state what license you have available. if you have info, you could use the `near` function. for editor license, check the option of a spatial join. i don't know if there's a way to account for the terrain though.